# Preserve Monitor Settings on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 with Xfce version 4.12.4

I often connect my laptop to my monitor. When I connect my monitor, this dialog shows up:
[image: Display Dialog]

I select Advanced and manually configure external monitor to be on the left as a primary display. However, when I unplug it and plug it back in later, the display settings don't preserve, so I have to manually configure it like before.

Is there any way to automatically configure the external monitor to be on the left as a primary display? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For years I have this issue as well! Drivers me insane now. Every-time I login into my machine. Start my machine, or when I come back to my machine. I need to reconfigure XFCE monitor settings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it myself. Instead of using Xfce's display configuration, I unchecked the box that said "Configure new displays when connected."
[image: Xfce Display Configuration Window]

I opted instead to use [autorandr](https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr).

To install it, simply follow the README instructions

> Save your current display configuration and setup with:
>
> `$ autorandr --save mobile`
>
> Connect an additional display, configure your setup and save it:
>
> `$ autorandr --save docked`

Now, your display should automatically configure depending if a monitor is connected or not.

Comment: I don't have that option in XFCE v4.18? I only see 'Mirror displays' there. I can disable this pop-up window at advanced settings. https://i.ibb.co/zZdFk1G/Screenshot-2023-04-18-18-18-29.png But my settings are constantly reset.

Comment: @askubuntu.com/users/18045/melroy-van-den-berg - I saw the same thing you did on the main display panel, but there is an "advanced" tab that does have the "configure new displays when connected" option. I saved a profile on the advanced tab and it did load that configuration when I restarted. Here's the reference document - https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/4.16/display